# Copy document with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a document class called "foo" defined as follows, in `foo.js`:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var fooSchema = mongoose.Schema({
user_id: String,
created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
flag: { type: Boolean, default: false },
etc: Number,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('foo', fooSchema);
```

and in my router, I want to instantiate an object, and an exact copy of that (`created_at` might differ a little, no problem :)), only changing the `flag` field. So I have two copies, one with "flag", one with "not flag". Trying this did not work as expected:

```
var Foo = require('../models/foo');
var myObj = new Foo();
myObj.user_id = req.user._id;
myObj.etc = 42;
myObj.save(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // // also create a "flag" copy
    // non-working code:
    var myObj2 = myObj; 
    myObj2.flag = true;
    myObj2.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("this does not create a new item");
    }); // myObj2.save();
    // working code:
    var myObj2 = new Foo();
    myObj2.user_id = myObj.user_id
    myObj2.etc = myObj.etc;
    myObj2.flag = true;
    myObj2.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("this works");
    }); // myObj2.save();
}); // myObj.save();
```

So what is wrong with `var myObj2 = myObj;`? Does it pass by reference? If so, how can I pass by value? Do I need to define a special constructor that takes an existing item as argument, so that I can call `var myObj2 = new Foo(myObj);`? Or any other way that I can replicate an existing item without duplicating so much code?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

1.Yes, you are passing reference that way.

2.you can try `myObj2 = myObj.toObject();` then `Foo.create(myObj2);`, but you might got a duplicate key error due to the same _id obj and obj2 share

Comment: Thanks! If I remove `myObj2._id`, will MongoDB create a valid key for me inside `myObj2.save();`?

Comment: Actually after `myObj2 = toObject()` just doesn't contain the method `save()'`since it's a plain js object. But when you called `Foo.create(myObj2)`, the Object it returns is a instance of Foo model. So, yes, delete the _id before Foo.create and it generates a valid _id for you.

Comment: Great! And one final question; does `.create()` exist natively, or do I need to define it inside `foo.js`? Thanks,

Comment: Simply use `Foo.create()`, along with methods like `Foo.findOne()`, `Foo.update()`, they are all built-in methods in mongoose model.